# How can I Insert and retrieve Time Field in SQL Server database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to handle Time insertion and selection in SQL Server database using C# ? I just want to save time. Any help would be appreciated.

Here I have included my code which is of course very simple on suggestion of one of my stack overflow mate.

In sql

```
[Time] Time
```

In Model

```
public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
```

In View

```
 @foreach (var item in query)
 {
    <span class="red-font">@item.Time</span>
 }

query is the collection of the objects
```

Thanks.

Comment: Time datatype is available in SQL

Comment: @Partha but not available in c# I think

Comment: What are you using to access the database, ADO.NET? In that case the Time sql datatype should [map to TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx). Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @vesan I am not using ADO.NET, I am using ORM Lite as my object relational mapper, and I have declared the field as TimeSpan in the class, my database contains value as 10:00:00 but it is giving output as 00:00:00.

Comment: Post your code please. Without it, it's difficult to help you (short of writing the entire code for you).

Comment: @vesan I have included the code as per your request